# Where to keep custom header items when using MessageInspector to use it later within the WCF

Tags: c#, wcf

When using the `MessageInspector` to add a custom header to every WCF call from the client, where to keep the custom header items after getting them in the `AfterReceiveRequest` method at the server end? I want to be able to access them later in the WCF server code. The custom header item will be a session number sent from the client.

```
public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message request, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel channel, System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext instanceContext)
    {
        int headerIndex = request.Headers.FindHeader("SessionID", string.Empty);
        if (headerIndex != -1)
        {
            // where to keep the custom header item?
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the header directly in your service by using  `OperationContext.Current`

Example:

```
public string GetData(int value)
{
    var headers = OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders;
    int headerIndex = headers.FindHeader("SessionID", string.Empty);
    ...
}
```

If you are concerned about unit testing, just wrap OperationContext.Current in a provider/service.

Example:

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    private ISessionInspector _sessionInspector; //will access OperationContext.Current

    public Service1(ISessionInspector sessionInspector)
    {
        _sessionInspector = sessionInspector;
    }
    public string GetData(int value)
    {
        var sessionId = _sessionInspector.GetCurrentSessionID();
        ...
    }
```